# MSMQ via HTTP - Why do we need TCP Port 1801?

Tags: windows-server-2008, http, port, msmq

Context: MSMQ, Windows Server 2008 (either "regular" or "R2" editions)

According to MS online documentation here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc725576%28WS.10%29.aspx

MSMQ messages can be transferred over HTTP.

However, the ports needed for such transport technique, are:

- 80
- 1801

Now, port 80 (or the host's default HTTP port, which is 80 for most cases) is trivial and understandable.

But TCP port 1801? Why? Isn't it pure HTTP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rest assured that the documentation is completely wrong on that point.
I am embarrassed because I never spotted what the product group wrote while I worked in MSMQ support at Microsoft.
I'll see if I can get someone to fix the information (Customer support request # 1158580154).

Comment: So you're saying the only port needed for HTTP is 80? BTW, would you please post a direct link to the customer support request (if it's public)? Thanks!

Comment: I just sent an email through Microsoft.com asking them to fix the article. I copied the SR down from the comfirmation page. The SR doesn't exist as a viewable web page AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, MSMQ over HTTP requires port 80. 
Note that if you want transaction messaging, you need to have MSMQ over HTTP installed at both ends so that the destination webserver can return ACK messages to the webserver on the sending machine. So you'd need port 80 open both ways in firewall configs which isn't always allowed for a webfarm.

Comment: Customer Service weren't a great help so I've Tweeted the lovely people at @ASKTechNetUK.

Comment: From Microsoft: "This will be updated within the next week or so – thanks so much for putting us right."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is an accurate statement. I scanned a machine recently with nmap and it had port 1801 open for MSMQ. Therefore, you must need to have 1801 open. If I understood the question correctly?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: NMAP sometimes "guesses" which services are running on which port, so the open port might or might not have been MSMQ.